# How to avoid multiple users accessing same test data in LR

Tags: loadrunner

i am using LR11.5, i have the following test data:
TestData
1
2
3
4
5
when i run this script from Controller with 3 users LR picks it as user1->1, user2->1, user3->1

How do i achieve this case: user1->1, user2->2, user3->3 ??

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use various coding techniques within your script but the LoadRunner recommended solution is to use VTS (shipped with LR). Read more about it here: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-LoadRunner-and-Performance/The-New-Virtual-Table-Server-VTS-in-LoadRunner-11-52/ba-p/6069435

edited: initially put the link to old VTS

edited2: Please use Unique as James Pulley suggest for simple cases and VTS for the more complex cases.

Answer (score 4):

See training documentation or LR Manuals regarding parameterization, UNIQUE attribute and block size.   Make sure you have enough data in your data file for the number of iterations multiplied by the number of users or all of your users will not start.